# drupal 7 PDOException error saying I'm missing a table or view mysite_drupal.cache_views

Tags: 7, views, database

The full warning message goes like this: `PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mysite_drupal.cache_views' doesn't exist: TRUNCATE {cache_views} ; Array ( ) in cache_clear_all() (line 165 of /home/user/mysite.com/includes/cache.inc)`.
should I try to manually create it?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the table exists in mysql?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if cache_views is missing and you have the Views module installed, you need to create it.

To do so, simply duplicate the standard cache table and rename it to cache_views; they share the same columns.

You might also need to re-create the cache_views_data table, also with the same columns.

Comment: as always, great ;)

Answer (score 2):

From a mysql command prompt, you can go

```
show create table cache;
```

That will show the create table syntax for a cache table.

Change the table name to cache_views and you can use that SQL to recreate the table.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `cache_views` (
  `cid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique cache ID.',
  `data` longblob COMMENT 'A collection of data to cache.',
  `expire` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp indicating when the cache entry should expire, or 0 for never.',
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp indicating when the cache entry was created.',
  `serialized` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A flag to indicate whether content is serialized (1) or not (0).',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
  KEY `expire` (`expire`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Generic cache table for caching views...'
```

You can also create the table in PHP with something similar to:

```
$schema['cache_views'] = drupal_get_schema_unprocessed('system', 'cache');
db_create_table('cache_views', $schema['cache_views']);
```

You may also need to recreate `cache_views_data` in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks, that got it. Why do you think those tables wouldn't be there though?